# Thymeleaf - Elvis operator not working as intended

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My code is the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid" th:object="${content}">
    <span th:text="*{poster}?: 'no poster'"></span>
</div>
```

If poster is null, then the span should display "no poster". Instead it displays "N/A":

```
<span>N/A</span>
```

When the poster is present, it behaves as expected.

I looked at the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator) and couldn't understand where my mistake is.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure value of `poster` is null and not `N/A`?

Comment: Yeah... the value of `${content.poster} is `N/A` instead of `null`. (There's no other possibility here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elvis operator only works for `null` values. `N/A` values aren't actually null.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I went and double checked my code and that was indeed the case. I forgot to add code that sets poster value to null if the value is "N/A". Thanks a lot!